# Access to asp.net web service

Tags: android, asp.net, web-services

I wrote a little WS on asp.net, I can open it printing something like

http://46.146.170.225/RouteGen/Service.asmx

in address bar. It's all right, WS works.

But if I print the same address in a browser on the other computer, the page isn't available. How to get access to my web server from other PC? (I need from Android device, but I think it's no difference)

Comment: Possibly blocked by Windows Firewall... can you get to any webpage on your web server?

Comment: Yes, the trouble is with only this WS page on the other computer. On the server I can access to any web method without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Verify that the website, in IIS, is bound to a public-facing IP address. Right click on your website in IIS, and go to the bindings setting. Then, check the host field. It should have an IP address or domain name that is available publicly.
2. Verify that your firewall has Port 80 open for incoming traffic

Comment: Yeah!I created a rule for port 80 in Windows Firewall and it works now!Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you started the Web-Service from within Visual Studio then without changing the starup-settings of your project - it's not possible, because VS only starts a local debug web-server that doesn't allow calls from other hosts than localhost.

To allow external IPs to access your web-server, you have to set up the IIS and run your web-service inside it. A firewall could block incoming requests to the IIS but I ran such a service last winter and didn't have to change firewall-settings.

Comment: Can you explain more particularly how to set up the IIS and run web-service inside it?I tried something but I don't know exactly what to do